# Em Python E Jupyter Notebook, como apresentar um registro completo em tela?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, ipython-notebook

estou no Jupyter Notebook trabalhando com Python.

Minhas colunas são strings e bem longas, preciso ver estas completas em tela, como fazer isso?

A imagem do dataframe com as strings "incompletas":

[image: Imagem do dataframe]

Meu desejo é ter a seguinte apresentação:

**nome_arquivo**

20181126100750UP5d4760ed369f42d5884bbdc47b4b9ee2.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a documentação você pode setar isso utilizando `max_colwidth`.

```
pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 40)

       0    1       2                          3
0    foo  bar     bim  uncomfortably long string
1  horse  cow  banana                      apple
```

Setando um valor menor

```
 pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 6)

       0    1      2      3
0    foo  bar    bim  un...
1  horse  cow  ba...  apple
```

Se não quer definir um limite use None: `pd.set_option("max_colwidth", None)`

Para mais informações sobre as [opções](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) que podem ser utilizadas.